# How to store template class in a vector?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, vector

I've following code and i want to store `Base<A> * a,Base<B> * b` in a vector without losing
typename,so i want to achieve `vector<.....> vec; vec.push_back(a); vec.push_back(b);` and  call like 
  this `vec[0]->DoJob(3,4); vector[1]->DoJob(3,4,"blablba");`.
How can i do it? I can change design completely if there is a way to accomplish this.

```
/*this code works*/
template<typename T>
class Base{
protected:
    virtual ~Base(){}
public:
    template<typename ... Args>
    void DoJob(Args ... args){
        T * t = dynamic_cast<T*>(this);
        t->print(args...);
    }
};


class A:public Base<A>{
public:
    void print(int a, int b){
        cout << a << b << endl;
    }
};

class B :public Base<B>{
public:
    void print(float a, double b, string s){
        cout << a << b << s << endl;
    }
};


Base<A> * a = new A();
a->DoJob(3, 4);
Base<B> * b = new B();
b->DoJob(3, 4,"blabla");
```

Comment: Can't you just add vector? `std::vector<Base<A>>`

Comment: nope.i dont know count of inherited classes and any types can be pushed into vector.

Comment: they are unrelated type, you can't put them in to a same vector without using boost variant or something similar

Comment: i dont know much about boost variant but i read about it,it is like union but problem is count of inherited classes unknown so i cant use boost variant template

Comment: Let's say you somehow get a vector that stores different types, each of them taking a different set of parameter for their print implementation. How do you want to use them? Because the caller would somehow have to know which parameters he has to pass for every element.

Comment: Why would you then use over a normal inheritance?

Comment: caller knows which parameter will be used from other things.problem is storing class without losing typename

Comment: @DRoW: Which other things ?

Comment: i ve stack and from stack situation i'm creating that classes and i know number of parameters from that classes.But main issue is store with type not this case.

Answer (score 1):

One fairly common way to implement something like that would be to have a container with a pointer to a common superclass.

```
class BaseSuperclass {
// ...
};

template<typename T> class Base : public BaseSuperclass {
// ...
};

std::vector<BaseSuperclass *> vector;
```

Then any `Base<T> *` can be pushed into your vector.

Note that when you iterate over, or retrieve the contents of your vector, all you'll end up getting back is a `BaseSuperclass *`. You'll then have to figure out which subclass you have at hand.

Comment: i need to know derived class so storing just basesuperclass without type it wont work for my situation.

Comment: There are many different techniques for obtaining the derived class of each instance. But, as far as storing pointers to those derived classes in a single vector, this is a fairly common way to do it. Getting the original derived class, that's a separate topic.